# How to style an element wit random css id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to style an Id from an external form rendered (javascript) on my site. Problem is that the ID is random like this:

1. page refresh one: div#4-register-form-container57287c94e2312
2. page refresh two: div#4-register-form-container35469e56e2278
3. page refresh tree: div#4-register-form-container6575c98e1274
4. page refresh four: div#4-register-form-container25242e33e6584
5. and so on...

If I try to style it without that the random number it won't works... Is it possible to style it?

Answer (score 5):

you can use the *starts-with* `^=` operator and group the `id` in `[]`:-

```css
div[id^="4-register-form-container"] {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="4-register-form-container25242e33e6584">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Use CSS selectors like `[id~="-register-form-container"]`.
Read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) more about selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[attribute^=value]` CSS selector.

ie, `div[id^="div#4-register-form-container"]` - Selects every  element whose `id` attribute value begins with `div#4-register-form-container`

```css
div[id^="div#4-register-form-container"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div#4-register-form-container57287c94e2312">
  Random div 1
</div>

<div id="div#4-register-form-container35469e56e2278">
  Random div 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with jQuery `$('div[id^=div#4-register-form-container]')` or `document.querySelectorAll('[id^="4-register-form-container"]');` for native JS